# Tesing Admob Tracking in Android App

Tags: android, admob

I want to implement Admob Tracking in my Android app. The Ads will be generated and published.
As far as I understand admob tracking is used to keep track of downloads of my app by means of the ads published. And to track this I need to have an app with tracking implemented in market. But is there any way to test if tracing is happening properly. Or am I not understanding the concept properly.

Any views are appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this in my APP and I believe only way to test this is having the APP in Marketplace.