# Android AdMob download Tracking Test

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an application, in which i have to add google admob download tracking. i.e., to check that number of the time the app has been downloaded from the android market. But for the time being app is not in android market as it is in development phase, to do so, i have added the code in xml as per the documentation in the manifest file within application tag:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.ads.InstallReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

What else i need to do, i have included the jar file as well, but what next ??? remember it's just download tracking not whole app tracking. Any help is appreciated. Thanks..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Tesing Admob Tracking in Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779617/tesing-admob-tracking-in-android-app)

With no response. The conclusion so far is that it can be tested only after the app is live with the tracking implemented.

Comment: hmm....almost same... but i need to know that do i have to modify some code as well or the only the addition in manifest file is enough..????

Comment: @ Tushar Vegurlekar ... can you give me an example code that how u implemented the google admob download tracking. not a link of wikipedia... an exmaple where it is done. it will be so nice of you if you do so. Thanks in advance..!!